# dropdown if image files using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dropdown of image icons. Now I want to change the dropdown's default page load icon to one selected by the user, using javascript. I am new to javascript but can not do it. FYI,I have included jquery files too. Please help.

```
 <li>
                            <div class="dropdown choose-theme" id="theme">
                                <a class="#" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><img src="img/theme/blue.png" alt="Blue"> Blue</a>
                                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#"><img src="img/theme/green.png" alt="Green" value="img/theme/green.png"> Green</a></li>
                                    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#"><img src="img/theme/grey.png" alt="Grey" value="img/theme/grey.png"> Grey</a></li>
                                    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#"><img src="img/theme/red.png" alt="Red" value="img/theme/red.png"> Red</a></li>
                                    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#"><img src="img/theme/orange.png" alt="Orange" value="img/theme/orange.png"> Orange</a></li>
                                    <li role="menuitem"><a href="#"><img src="img/theme/blue.png" alt="Blue" value="img/theme/blue.png"> Blue</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </li>
```

Custom javascript I was trying

```
$(function()
{
$('#theme ul li').click(function({
var $a  = $(this).find('a');
$(this).parents('#theme').children('a').replaceWith($a);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#theme ul li a').click(function(){
     $(this).parents('#theme').children('a').html($(this).html());
   });
});
```

Comment: EDIT: I need another favour how to pull the value attribute from the $(this).html()?

Answer (score 0):

You were missing a couple of parentheses and curlies there:

```
$(function(){

    $('#theme ul li').click(function(){
      var $a  = $(this).find('a');
      $('#theme').children('a').replaceWith( $a.clone() );
    });

});
```

I replaced `$(this).parents('#theme')` with just `$('theme')` (it's an ID, you should always one and don't need to traverse to find it).
Also did `$a.clone();`, otherwise the clicked link would actually be removed from the list.

Comment: I need another favour how to pull the value attribute from the $(this).html()

Comment: Not sure what you mean by this, can you please explain?

Comment: Basically, if I print the $(this).html() it is providing me the entire inner html like img src="img/theme/grey.png" alt="Grey" value="img/theme/grey.png"> Grey. But I want the value part only, is there a method for it? Not sure it is called attribute or element? It is pretty silly but still cant seem to achieve it

Comment: value="img/theme/green.png" I meant this part (inside the quotes). Not sure value is called attribute or class or something else

Comment: It's an attribute. Is this always the same as `src` though? `$(this).find('img').attr('src')` or `$(this).find('img')[0].src` would work (within scope of the `click` callback). A `value` attribute on a image tag is not actually valid afaik, so if you actually want it to be something else than `src` (if not, just get rid of it), you should write `data-value="..."` and then do `$(this).find('img').data('value')`